# Fastest way to get values from dictionary to another dictionary in python without using if?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, if-statement

I need to find a way to get values from one dictionary to another, bases on key name match without using two loops \ if statement.

Main goal is to make it run more efficiently since it's a part of a larger code and run on multiple threads.

If you can keep the dictionary structure it would help

The second dict is initialized with values 0 in advanced

```
dict_1 = {
    "school": {
        "main": ["first_key"]
    },
    "specific": {
        "students": [
            {
                "name": "sam",
                "age": 13
            },
            {
                "name": "dan",
                "age": 9
            },
            {
                "name": "david",
                "age": 20
            },
            {
                "name": "mike",
                "age": 5
            }
        ],
        "total_students": 4
    }
}

dict_2 = {'sam': 0, 'mike': 0, 'david': 0, 'dan': 0, 'total_students': 0}

for i in dict_1["specific"]['students']:
    for x in dict_2:
        if x == i["name"]:
            dict_2[x] = i["age"]

    dict_2["total_students"] = dict_1["specific"]["total_students"]

print(dict_2)
```

Is there more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two loops at all! You don't even need to initialize `dict_2` in advance. Simply loop over `dict_1["specific"]["students"]` and assign the ages to `dict_2` without an `if`.

```
for student in dict_1["specific"]["students"]:
    student_name = student["name"]
    student_age = student["age"]
    dict_2[student_name] = student_age
```

You could also write this as a comprehension:

```
dict_2 = {student["name"]: student["age"] for student in dict_1["specific"]["students"]}
```

Both these give the following `dict_2`:

```
{'sam': 13, 'dan': 9, 'david': 20, 'mike': 5}
```

Then you can set `dict_2["total_students"]` like you already do, but outside any loops.

```
dict_2["total_students"] = dict_1["specific"]["total_students"]
```

If you only want to assign ages for students already in `dict_2`, you need the `if`. However, you can still do this with a single loop instead of two. :

```
for student in dict_1["specific"]["students"]:
    student_name = student["name"]
    if student_name not in dict_2:
        continue # skip the rest of this loop

    student_age = student["age"]
    dict_2[student_name] = student_age
```

Both these approaches use a single loop, so they're going to be faster than your two-loop approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in dict_1['specific']['students']:
 dict_2[i['name']]=i['age']

dict_2['total_students']=dict_1['specific']['total_students']
```

Runs in O(N) time and O(N) space.
Yours currently runs in O(N^2) time and O(N) space